# No Audio from Brave Browser , but works when Switch Account

Tags: 20.04, sound, firefox, chromium, brave

For a few months I have been troubleshooting no audio coming from brave-browser installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. For example, if I use the same YouTube URL in Brave and Firefox, I get audio from Firefox but not Brave. This lack of audio still occurs if I do a fresh install of Brave, Brave-beta, Brave-nightly, or Chromium - suggesting an issue with Chromium based browsers. **Again, however, audio does work when I use Firefox.**

However, if I switch user from my main account to another account, I do get audio from the Brave browser when I use that same URL.

I think this is strong evidence that something is awry with my main account. But I am not sure what settings would prevent audio coming from Chromium based browsers (like Brave + Chromium) but not prevent audio from FireFox.

I was hopeful someone might have a suggestion for where to look for what may be awry in my main profile.

Here is the link where I have been troubleshooting the issue:
https://community.brave.com/t/ubuntu-no-audio-from-brave-but-working-from-firefox/448355/18

Comment: please look in your $HOME for configs from your brave browser. I hope it is not a snap or flatpack.

Comment: Found $HOME/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser. Did a strong rm -rf. But still no audio from this account (although there is audio when I switch accounts). Installed via the Brave suggested route (https://brave.com/linux/)

Comment: Okay will install it tomorrow.

Comment: start brave browser (for example with a youtube link) And then look in gnome-control-center tab sound if is it set on for brave. I'm running lubuntu so I do not know exactly the names for it. Check also in pavucontrol the setting for this audio-stream (loudness).

Comment: So if I open pavucontrol and play a YouTube link in Firefox, under 'Output Devices' I see a bar above advanced increases and decreases depending on the amplitude of the output from the YouTube video. However, I don't see that similar behavior when I play a YouTube video in brave. It seems pavucontrol doesn't even know there is media/audio coming from the Brave-Browser. Again, oddly, if I change the Ubuntu-Login to 'test', I do see audio, however.

Comment: Ah and similarly, if I go under 'Playback' I see a slider for FireFox but not for Brave.

Comment: you can try to reset your desktop.  `gsettings list-schemas | xargs -n 1 gsettings reset-recursively`  and `dconf reset -f /`  but be warned this reset complete your desktop settings to default. Log out and log in again.

Comment: Just gave it a go. Still no audio from brave, but continued audio from Firefox. (but still get audio from brave on a different account). But did have to reset keyboard shortcuts, desktop background (indicating that the command worked, but did not fix whatever setting is preventing audio from Brave even getting detected by pavucontrol)

Comment: On both users `find $HOME - iname '*pulse*' ` please. There must be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After months of troubleshooting, I discovered I had both a Brave recommended installed version of Brave (i.e. through their website) and a snap installation of Brave. While I am not sure how this resulted in no audio from the browser, deletion of all snap based software restored the audio function of brave.